# How do I get content from push notification?

Tags: ios, swift

Using Swift3 with xcode8.3

Below is my function code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("==== didReceiveRemoteNotification ====")
    print(userInfo)

    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState

    if state == .background {
        // background
        if let pushUrl = userInfo[AnyHashable("url")] as? String {
            viewController?.redirectTo(url: pushUrl)
        }
    }
    else if state == .active {
        // foreground
        print("==== foreground Running ====")
        let pushUrl = userInfo[AnyHashable("url")]
        let pushApns = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")]
        let pushAlert = pushApns["alert"]
        viewController?.showAlertBox(url: pushUrl as! String, msg: pushAlert)
    }
}
```

When I receive a notification on foreground, I need to get the content from it and pass it to viewController.

below is the log from my Xcode

```
==== didReceiveRemoteNotification ====
[AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "this is alert";
    badge = 0;
}, AnyHashable("url"): https://www.google.com]
```

But the code above is not working? How can I get "alert" and "url" content from notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! Try the following:

```
let data = userInfo as! [String: AnyObject]

if let url = data["url"] {
    print(url)
}

if let aps = data["aps"] {
    print(aps["alert"])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access alert try  using

```
if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
     if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
      //Use alert
    }
    if let alert = aps["badge"] as? NSNumber {
      //Use badge
    }
}
  if let url = userInfo["url"] as? String {
 // use url
}
```

Comment: This gives a "Type 'Any' has no subscript members" error for me.

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry you need to convert it to type [String:AnyObject] or of type NSDictionary